# Post a search value with toolbar filter in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm trying to use the filtertoolbar but I don't know how to send to the server the search values.

I'm using the jqGrid datatype: 'json' without loadonce:true. So the server is responsible for sorting, paging and filtering of the data. Then I send values to the server doing something like this....

```
     datatype: function () {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "Default2.aspx/GetPersons", //PageMethod

                data: "{'pPageSize':'" + $('#grid').getGridParam("rowNum") +
                "','pCurrentPage':'" + $('#grid').getGridParam("page") +
                "','pSortColumn':'" + $('#grid').getGridParam("sortname") +
                "','pSortOrder':'" + $('#grid').getGridParam("sortorder") +
                "','search':'" + $('#grid').getGridParam("**SEARCH VALUES HERE**") + "'}", 

                dataType: "json",
                type: "post",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                complete: function (jsondata, stat) {
                    if (stat == "success")
                        jQuery("#grid")[0].addJSONData(JSON.parse(jsondata.responseText).d);
                    else
                        alert(JSON.parse(jsondata.responseText).Message);
                }
            }); //Fin de AJAX
        }, //FIN de Funcion dentro de DataType
```

but I don't If I'm doing it right.

If someone can help me i would be so nice